# Why TypeScript doesn't infer the correct type when redeclaring a variable

Tags: typescript

I was writing a code that goes a little bit like this:

```
function helloWorld(customName: string) {
  return `Hello, ${customName}`;
}

const myName: string | null = null;
const isValidName = myName !== null;

if (isValidName) {
  console.log(helloWorld(myName));
}
```

If you [run this code in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wOpwE7oAmAFBCAM5RwC2AcgIbWoBcileMYA5gJSIDeAKESI8qKCDxIABgAkMWADSIAJPzKUaDJgF9pAbkE7BgiAkqJqAT20s2UDt0QAfRGBCZEAXjcf0hszALGHIANXp0GEJbb0sbRlREAEIvH3dMQ0EYYERiEPDI6IS%20IRFA8jh0VAA6LC5iNEwcfCJia1seHkMdIA), you'll see TypeScript will complain that `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

How's that the case, though? That code only runs when `isValidName` is truthy and `isValidName` can only be `true` if `myName` is not `null`. Hence, `myName` is a `string` here. Why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand - that fact that you're storing the result of `myName !== null` into the variable `isValidName` enforces the TypeScript to check that value in the runtime and behave appropriately (so calling `helloWorld(myName)` seems illegal because `isValidName` can be potentially either `true` or `false` in runtime).

However, if you change the check to be

```
if (myName !== null) {
  console.log(helloWorld(myName));
}
```

TypeScript will be able to detect that the only possible type of `myName` can be a `string` in those circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you have written this, typescript sees that `isValidName` is a `boolean` constant and that's it.

You, the code author, know that the value of `isValidName` indicates something about the value of `myName`, but typescript doesn't consider the relationship between the two variables.

What you want is for your `if` statement to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).  Essentially a type guard is a boolean value computed at runtime which depends on the value of `myName` and whether than boolean is `true` or `false` provides some information which narrows the type definition of `myName`.

As @falinsky pointed out, `myName !== null` is fine as a type guard *if you use it inside the condition of your `if` statement*.  It says, "if this is `true` then `myName` is not `null`".

You can also create `isValidName` as a function which checks a name and determines that it is a string.

```
const isValidName = (name: string | null): name is string => {
  return name !== null;
}

if (isValidName(myName)) {
  console.log(helloWorld(myName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the result of narrow downing in `isValidName` for further use and don't want to re-compute it, you can create a utility function like this

```js
/**
 * @param a The precomputed result
 * @param _b The variable to be narrowed down
 * @template T The type to which `_b` will be narrowed down to when `a` is true
 */
function typeCheck<T>(a: boolean, _b: any): _b is T {
  return a
}
```

Use like this

```js
if (typeCheck<string>(isValidName, myName)) {
  console.log(helloWorld(myName)); // string here
} else {
  console.log(myName) // null here
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWwJ4DkpsQAueTGASxQHN4AfeFAVwggCh2B6AKh-fg94AAQAOsIvCjwAKgAsEouMmyjmGEMHhw0rDAKFiJ2eAH0ARrIXwAbrEpRzEBBiTxzCFLBhIA7pvhgPxQDEQ1VaA1ZKxdcURc3XzlKMDl4AAMLdPhfSjZ3T28-AKDfFHhXHIVy9KhsyjQKmGYQAy52ADNmFDAMSlQKuJAAYQUwAGsAHhkAPgAKKDJzJCRnKBQAGjNzMnXcAEoyC3gG6IBvAW0QDGYYcqh2AF9OLp6+gYU2JAB1JBgIYBzMDMTBIbCEYhkCjUGj7eAXeBXG53DIACRAXy2ABIzsDQeCiCBHukANxPTjIdBYBoANSgEEowAhCAAvDgCIT4ABCFlslhsMnsSloVYgAB0ECQNDmtPpjOZ+04lA68DmGCGo3AU2htHmsoZTMJWzwCrhCMQqBFzglUrmn0lv3+gJNhP2+zJj3gGLQCHNwtFNulLuIiseQA)

This can be helpful when computing long expressions like

```js
if (
    isLoneAvailableCapacity(feed) &&
    (isAvailableCapacitySubbeamPath(link) || isAvailableCapacityConnectivityLegPath(link)) &&
    toAvailableCapacityKey(feed.availableCapacity) === link.availableCapacityKey
) {
    // do something
}

// snip....
// some more code

if (
    isLoneAvailableCapacity(feed) &&
    (isAvailableCapacitySubbeamPath(link) || isAvailableCapacityConnectivityLegPath(link)) &&
    toAvailableCapacityKey(feed.availableCapacity) === link.availableCapacityKey
) {
    // do something else
}
```

It can be replaced easily by

```js
const isValidFeed = isLoneAvailableCapacity(feed) &&
    (isAvailableCapacitySubbeamPath(link) || isAvailableCapacityConnectivityLegPath(link)) &&
    toAvailableCapacityKey(feed.availableCapacity) === link.availableCapacityKey

if(typeCheck<Feed>(isValidFeed, feed)) {
  // do something
}

// snip....
// some more code

if(typeCheck<Feed>(isValidFeed, feed)) {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a good job explaining workarounds, but don't explain *why*.

The simple fact is that Typescript is *not yet* sophisticated enough to understand multiple dependent variables.

It's very possible that in the future features for this will get added. There's no reason why this *couldn't* work, but I imagine it is simply difficult.

I hope one day this does work, because it also makes some of the stuff I'm doing simpler.